# Steps in visual c++ to start a toolbar button project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

I would like to start a new VC++ project that can create a toolbar button for Internet Explorer in the form of DLL.

Yes, I know there are complete source code example at Code Project. But the example are already created/generated by the original developer. So I lack the knowledge on how actually to start a new project like that. Which wizard to select and so on.

Please guide me.

Comment: you've asked 26 questions, and 18 of them didn't get any answer at all.  This is not typical, and is because you seem to be asking rather elementary questions without detail, specifics, or making *any* attempt at the work prior to posting a question.  For your own benefit, please reconsider how you approach problem solving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing Internet Explorer toolbars and extensions is no easy task. For starters, it requires some intimate knowledge of [Component Object Model (COM)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model), some [ATL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Template_Library), and probably a bit of [WTL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WTL) as well. You will at least need to understand C++ and COM pretty well before you can even begin to understand the Internet Explorer stuff. And COM, ATL, and WTL are not mainstream topics anymore. So you won't find many resources to help you.

If you're having difficulty knowing what buttons to click in the IDE, it's probably safe to say that it's too early for you to take on a project like the.